# image rotation, covers the button

Tags: objective-c

I want to rotate the image around the x-axis from left to right. The problem is that when you rotate the image covers the button located on the top

### Run animation

```
   [AnimationUtil rotationRightToLeftForView:image andDuration:1];
```

```
Animation metod
```

+(void) rotationRightToLeftForView:(UIView *)flipView andDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

`// Remove existing animations before stating new animation
[flipView.layer removeAllAnimations];

// Make sure view is visible
flipView.hidden = NO;

// show 1/2 animation  
//flipView.layer.doubleSided = NO;

// disable the view so it’s not doing anythign while animating
flipView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
// Set the CALayer anchorPoint to the left edge and
// translate the button to account for the new
// anchorPoint. In case you want to reuse the animation
// for this button, we only do the translation and
// anchor point setting once.


if (flipView.layer.anchorPoint.x != 0.0f) {
    flipView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
    flipView.center = CGPointMake(flipView.center.x-flipView.bounds.size.width/2.0f, flipView.center.y);
}    

// create an animation to hold the page turning    
CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
transformAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
transformAnimation.duration = duration;
transformAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
// start the animation from the current state
transformAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];

// this is the basic rotation by 180 degree along the y-axis M_PI
CATransform3D endTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians(180.0), 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

transformAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:endTransform];   

// Create an animation group to hold the rotation
CAAnimationGroup *theGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];

// Set self as the delegate to receive notification when the animation finishes
theGroup.delegate = self;
theGroup.duration = duration;
// CAAnimation-objects support arbitrary Key-Value pairs, we add the UIView tag
// to identify the animation later when it finishes
[theGroup setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:flipView.tag] forKey:@"viewFlipTag"];
// Here you could add other animations to the array
theGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:transformAnimation, nil];
theGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;   
// Add the animation group to the layer
[flipView.layer addAnimation:theGroup forKey:@"flipView"];`

}

Comment: OK, and how can we help you with this?

Comment: I wanted the image rotated under the button. How can I make?

Comment: image problem http://s018.radikal.ru/i505/1202/d2/5f732e4bb421.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision follows:
Create mask (image) Color = black, make region Size = Button.size  Color = transparent
image name = "mask2.png"

```
button = ...;
ImageView = ...;
parent_view = ...;

UIImage *_maskingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask2"];
CALayer *_maskingLayer = [CALayer layer];
_maskingLayer.frame = parent_View.bounds;
[_maskingLayer setContents:(id)[_maskingImage CGImage]];

CALayer *layerForImage = [[CALayer alloc] init];
layerForImage.frame = parent_View.bounds;
[layerForImage setMask:_maskingLayer];
[layerForImage addSublayer:ImageView.layer];

[parent_View.layer addSublayer:layerForImage];
[parent_View addSubView:button];
```